# What is the reason to use this.each() in jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here are two examples that lead to same result - the plugin is executed for each item of the sequence. So what is the reason to use `this.each` in jQuery plugins?

Without `this.each`:

```
$.fn.green = function () {
   this.css({color: "green"});
   return this;
}
```

With `this.each`:

```
$.fn.green = function () {
    return this.each(function(index, elem) {
        $(elem).css({color: "green"});
    });
}
```

Documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method

Comment: In that example there is no difference, since `css` method iterates through the collection.

Comment: @Vohuman, but jQuery documentation doesn't give more reasonable explanation

Comment: It depends on what the plugin does. In most cases you need to iterate through the collection in order to do something specific for each element.

Comment: Swap the functions at http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zuhr6xuo/ and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The point is to isolate instances of elements within the selector collection.

Taking your example a small step further lets consider that the color is dependent on some class on the parent of each element.

```
$.fn.green = function () {
    return this.each(function(index, elem) {
        var $el =$(this), $parent = $el.parent();
        var color = $parent.is('.someClass') ? 'green' : 'red';
        $el.css({color: color});
    });
}
```

Now the instances can have different color depending on other conditions relating to that instance